# Django query returns empty every time after nginx restart

Tags: python, django, nginx, wsgi, django-wsgi

As I said in the title, I restarted the nginx server for my site and then made a query to the db that I had done many times before.  I can see that the db wasn't accidentally wiped, and I can see that the request payload is still correct.  I didn't change any of the code relating to db access, so why is this happening?

here is the Nginx configuration file:

```
events {
worker_connections 768;
# multi_accept on;
}
http {

##
# Basic Settings
##

sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
keepalive_timeout 65;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
# server_tokens off;

# server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
# server_name_in_redirect off;

include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;

##
# Logging Settings
##

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

##
# Gzip Settings
##

gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

# gzip_vary on;
# gzip_proxied any;
# gzip_comp_level 6;
# gzip_buffers 16 8k;
# gzip_http_version 1.1;
# gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

##
# nginx-naxsi config
##
# Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
##

#include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

##
# nginx-passenger config
##
# Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
##

#passenger_root /usr;
#passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

##
# Virtual Host Configs
##

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

Comment: Please show the code that isn't working.

Comment: I have a selector on my site that asks the db to filter out all people who graduated after a certain year.  I didn't change the code, and it was working before.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is not to restart Nginx.

What is the query? How is Nginx configured? How and why are you restarting it?

Comment: The query is just asking for all people in the db who graduated between 2013 and 2015.  I was led to believe that after making a change to the nginx configuration, one had to restart it to apply the change.  I changed the configuration back and restarted again, but still no luck.  I don't have enough characters to paste the whole configuration.  What is the relevant info you are looking for?

Comment: oh, and I restarted nginx using "service nginx restart"

Comment: It is correct that you need to restart Nginx when you make changes and your method is also normal. Please edit your question sharing the relevant Nginx configuration file. We need to know how Nginx is forwarding the requests to Django.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer. It doesn't provide any useful information to solve the problem.

Comment: TerryMartin: Your config shows that the relevant parts are under /etc/nginx/.
@ShangWang: Yes you are correct. I could not add a comment to the question because I lack the reputation points.

Comment: These are the files in the directory.  Any clue which one I should be looking at?  Thanks for helping, by the way.  koi-win    naxsi.rules        proxy_params sites-enabled
fastcgi_params mime.types   naxsi-ui.conf.1.4.1  scgi_params uwsgi_params
koi-utf  naxsi_core.rules  nginx.conf        sites-available win-utf